# Connecting Android with Openstack services

Tags: android, storage, google-cloud-storage, openstack, openstack-swift

I have been searching alot for any tutorial or something where I can connect an Android Client with Openstack swift services. What I am planning to do is to create a client that synchronizes the user-data and content from the phone to the Cloud.

I know it is also done by Android itself through Auto-Backup but is it possible for Open stack which I deployed on my PC and wants to provide storage services to the user?

Any guidance in this regard will be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to build an Android app ...

I've had some success using the jstack Javascript SDK for OpenStack to build a PhoneGap app that connected to the OpenStack cloud at Rackspace (Disclaimer: I am an employee at Rackspace).

Hope this helps.